# Free reverse proxy with SSL for Windows

Tags: windows, proxy

I am looking for (free) very simple reverse proxy solution (application) which supports SSL.

I tried Charles, it works great, but it is too complex and it's not free.

I have a little service which listen only on localhost:4952 and checks source hostname. With reverse proxy I am able to redirect request to the 4952 port:

https://92.168.1.10:1988 (SSL) -> redirect https://localhost:4952 (SSL)

Answer (score 5):

Nginx supports Windows and is free both in price and license (2-clause BSD-style). It supports encrypted and unencrypted reverse proxy for HTTP, mail (SMTP/POP/IMAP), and even for TCP. The Windows support isn't complete, known issues including the fact that only one worker can be used and the like, but it should still work.

More information can be found here:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am playing with nginx,  so far without lucky:   server { listen       1988 ssl; server_name  localhost;  location / { proxy_pass  https://localhost:41952;  }

Comment: Thanks. I have wasted a lot of time on "simple" proxy servers bugs and poor config for development. It never occurred to me that nginx could run on windows!

Comment: Nginx for windows is unsuitable for production as it supports only one worker process. From the docs "high performance and scalability should not be expected. Due to this and some other known issues version of nginx for Windows is considered to be a beta version." http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html).  It works on Windows.
Based on this [Windows](https://www.stunnel.org/config_windows.html) sample.  Your config may look something like:

```
; Debugging stuff (may be useful for troubleshooting)
debug = info
output = stunnel.log

[myservice]
accept  = 3000
connect = 4952
cert = myservicecert.pem
```

Comment: I am playing with stunnel, but it's not working: http://serverfault.com/questions/727855/stunnel-ssl-to-ssl

Comment: Oh you didn't say the back end was also SSL.  No wonder you had problems.